# Regex find urls and replace with bbcode

Tags: regex

I'm writing program that replace link with bbcode. I need a regex that replace url with bbcode, example:

**before**

```
http://mediafire.com/abc (or http://dropbox.net/abc,...)
```

I want to filter that name of link also

**after**

```
[url=http://name-of-link.com/abc]http://name-of-link.com/abc[/url]
```

This is what I have got so far:

Search for:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?
```

Replace with:

```
[url=$1]$2[/url]
```

But it seems doesn't work. Hope anyone can help me out this issue. Thank you.

Edit:

My issue that I want to filter name of link also, because I don't want to replace link of image to bbcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: @MarcB No mate, My issue that I want to filter name of link also, because I don't want to replace link of image to bbcode

Comment: You forgot to mention that in the question. Generally images are not recognizable from the URL itself. You can only guess that urls ending in e.g. `.jpg` or `.png` are probably images, but they don't have to be.

Comment: what is a name of link? this is not clear.

Comment: @perreal mediafire or dropbox

Comment: @Wormbo Yes, could you please help me?

Comment: IMO you need to write an actual example of what you want. In the above the expected result is confusing.

Comment: @TheHung Don't know the language you're using, but can you try my generic shortcode processing library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode ? Ping me if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one:

```
^((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]))
```

replace (bb code)

```
- [url]($1)[/url]
```

replace (markup)

```
- [$1]($1)
```